# How do I use spool in sql server studio 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, export, spool

I have 14 sql select statements, all yielding different records. I need all 14 results stored in 14 different csv/txt files upon running the statements on my computer. I would also like to specify the names of all files. Using SQL Server Management Studio 2008. I was told that Spool is a good way to store query results in different formats, but does not look like it can be used in SQL 2008. How do I go about using it?

Any information on another way to go about this would be welcome.

Note:  I am not allowed to use the SSIS package though. :(

Comment: is this a continuous process? i mean, will it dynamically occur with a support of an application?

Comment: I did not get your question, the statements will be executed and results need to be stored in the files. I only need output files to be generated and stored automatically rather than me storing them by giving names to all 14 files. I hope this clears things.